# Timer schedule being passed weird number

Tags: java, android

I have some code in an Android `Activity` that runs a timer in order to update a UI element every minute. The code starting the timer is called in onResume() like this:

```
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateUtc();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        // update the time at the next time the minute rolls over
        long delay = 61000 - System.currentTimeMillis() % 60000L;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, delay, 60000L);
```

I have logged errors from this app in the wild throwing an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal delay to start the TimerTask: -1560105959000
at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:567)
at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:528)
```

I can't see how my code could possibly have produced a large negative number like that. Even if `currentTimeMillis()` returned a negative number the result of the whole calculation would still be positive. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: don't you think it will create a new time task every time onresume triggered. bad isn't it ?

Comment: @PavneetSingh Of course it creates a new task.  Since I don't want the timer running when the activity is paused, the TimerTask is cancelled in `onPause()`. A cancelled TimerTask can't be reused, so it's necessary to create a new one each time. The Timer, OTOH, is created in `onCreate()` and cancelled in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: because the `long delay = 61000 - System.currentTimeMillis() % 60000L;` will return minus value

Comment: cool, i missed the onpause code

Comment: @MoshErsan No, that expression cannot be negative, if evaluated according to the Java specification.

Comment: @Clyde can you try to add parentheses to be like this: `long delay = 61000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() % 60000L);`

Comment: @MoshErsan Adding parentheses would have no effect as % already has priority over -. There is nothing wrong with my code, the problem lies in the internals of the timer code, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. The text of the exception is misleading. The code for `scheduleAtFixedRateImpl()` looks like this:

```
   long when = delay + System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (when < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal delay to start the TimerTask: " + when);
```

So the value being printed is not the delay, but the absolute time calculated by adding the delay to the current system time. If the system has a date set that is prior to 1970, `currentTimeMillis()` returns a negative number. So the short answer is that you can't use the Android timer functions if the device has a date prior to 1970.

Answer (score 0):

I think Modulo is processed before subtraction. So this might do the trick:

```
( 61000 - System.currentTimeMillis() ) % 60000L
```

Comment: The modulo should have the priority even without the brackets.